# Model Binding without EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, asp.net-4.5

Is it possible to use Model binder features of Asp.Net 4.5 without using Entity Framwork?

If yes then how, no then why?

Currently we are using plain sql query to retrive/update/insert/detele data to/from database.
now we require to use Model Binder feature in our application without EF.

Can anyone tell me whether this is possible or not?

it would be good if you provide small examples.

Comment: Yes it is possible. What makes you think it's not?

Comment: Do you use ASP.NET WebForms, or MVC?

Comment: @haim770 : Because currenlty I have use Datasource/Databind method to bind data with gridview. Now I don't know How to bind data with ModelBinder.